# SQLite Query Confusion, Less than Greater than

Tags: android, database, search, sqlite

I give a function a DAY and an HOUR and I want to fetch COLUMN_DAY1=day and HOUR in between the two text-not-null columns COLUMN_FROM1 and COLUMN_TO1. Weird thing is that if I give say hour 7, and FROM1 and TO1 contain 6 and 9 respectively, it will return a positive search. If I give hour 12 and FROM1 and TO1 containt 11 and 17 respectively the search works.

BUT, when I give 7 and FROM1 and TO1 contain 6 and 10 respectively the search doesn't work. I think it's related to 10 being two digit and 6 being one digit or SOMETHING ALONG THOSE LINES.
Below is the cursor query I use please help, and what am I doing wrong?

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY1 +" ='" + Day+
                        "' AND " +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FROM1 + " <=" + Hour+
                        " AND " +MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO1+ " >" +Hour
                        , null, null, null, null);
```

Edit: It should also return true when COLUMN_FROM1 contains 6 and COLUMN_TO1 contains 10.

Function which writes data into SQLite Database:

```
InputStream is =getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ems_data);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

        int current = 0;

        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {

            baf.append((byte) current);

        }

        byte[] myData = baf.toByteArray();
        String dataInString = new String(myData);
        String[] lines = dataInString.split("\n");

        for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
            comment = datasource.createComment(lines[i]);
            // adapter.add(comment);
        }
```

EDIT:

The createComment(); Function:

```
public Comment createComment(String comment) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //parse data in string comment
        String[] words = comment.split("\\t");

        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, words[0]); //adds to column "name"
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT, words[1]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY1, words[2]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FROM1, words[3]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO1, words[4]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DAY2, words[5]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FROM2, words[6]);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_TO2, words[7]);

        //expected error above after DAY2 since it can be NULL

        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,
                values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Comment newComment = cursorToComment(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newComment;
    }
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Which records should be returned?

Comment: @cl- I made some progress so I edited the question completely. Please look again.

Comment: What are the types of the values in the database and of your variables? Please show the code that inserts the from/to values.

Comment: They are text not null. I'll add the code. I copy it from a TXT to the DB.

Comment: The code that inserts the from/to values would be in the `createComment` function.

Comment: @cl- updated with createComment(), I'm also thinking along the lines of faulty parsing btw...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

Parsing was not done BEAUTIFULLY correctly and end of line character \r was causing problems where SQLite Database was not recognizing the end '9' as a `9`. Added this line:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
```

Before I parsed the data with the \t delimiter and it worked!